# Getting an uninitialized constant error with RSpec. Have no idea what's causing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, spork

I'm using RSpec for testing and when I left work Friday afternoon, my tests were passing. But when I went home and synced my repository, the tests failed on my laptop. Now back at work, the tests are failing still. Don't believe its my code since running rspec by itself returns an error and spork won't even start up. When I try to start Spork, I get the following error message:

```
Using RSpec
Loading Spork.prefork block...
uninitialized constant ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::ENCODING_FLAG (NameError)
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-core-2.2.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:85:in `<class:ERB>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:70:in `<module:Handlers>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:28:in `<class:Template>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:27:in `<module:ActionView>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb:10:in `extended'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:99:in `extend'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:99:in `<class:Template>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:8:in `<module:ActionView>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_view/testing/resolvers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-rails-2.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/rspec-rails-2.2.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:33:in `rescue in require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/home/jeff/Projects/Rails/vahsfbhistory/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork.rb:23:in `prefork'
/home/jeff/Projects/Rails/vahsfbhistory/spec/spec_helper.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `load'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in preload'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/app_framework.rb:64:in `preload'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork.rb:67:in `exec_prefork'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork/runner.rb:9:in `run'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/gems/spork-0.8.4/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: did you ever find out why you were getting this error? I'm now experiencing this myself. All I did was require 'rspec/rails'

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this problem. In the spec_helper.rb try replacing:

```
require "rails"
```

with

```
require "rails/all"
```

Worked in my situation.

Comment: this did not fix my problem on my Rails 4.2.5 app

Answer (score 11):

You need to initialize environment, add this line to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Comment: @Зелёный answered just in time :)

Comment: this DID fix the symptom on my Rails 4.2.5 app

Answer (score 1):

You may encounter this issue if you're trying to use `rspec-rails` in a non-rails project. In that case using `require "rails/all"` is not an option because it'd require ActiveRecord stuff leaving you with:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with 'primary' found.`

Instead you can fix this issue with:

`require "action_controller/railtie"`

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with my non-rails project set up.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not a Rails app and you don't want to include all of Rails, add this to your *spec_helper.rb*:

```
require 'action_view'
```

Comment: This does not work on a non-rails app. Fails with `NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::TestCase`. See my answer instead.