# Installing RSpec, Capybara and Selenium Webdriver with Rails 4.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, activesupport

I'm following [Hartl's RoR tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages), but with updated software versions. Can you tell me how to set up the testing tools (What commands to run, and what the full contents of spec_helper should be). When I try to run RSpec from the terminal, I get a variety of errors. Fixing one error by requiring a file that StackOverflow recommends exposes another error. I'd like to create one wiki of the right way to set up Capybara + RSpec with Rails.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>=2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '>=2.4.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'active_support'
require 'rails/all'

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'


# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, make a
# separate helper file that requires this one and then use it only in the specs
# that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed

  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Enable only the newer, non-monkey-patching expect syntax.
    # For more details, see:
    #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
    mocks.syntax = :expect

    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
=end
# require 'rails/all'
# require 'capybara/rails'
# require 'capybara/rspec'
end
```

Current error:

```
$ rspec
/home/neilsatra/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /home/neilsatra/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.4.1/lib/capybara.rb
        from /home/neilsatra/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in  `<main>'
        from /home/neilsatra/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in  `load'
```

---

Previous errors (so people can Google this answer):

Various errors of the form "uninitialized constant  (NameError)", where something could be "ActiveSupport::Autoload", "Rails" or "ActionView::Template::Handlers::ERB::ENCODING_FLAG"

Related questions I've already looked at:

1. [Getting an unitialized constant error with RSpec. Have no idea what's causing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429068/getting-an-unitialized-constant-error-with-rspec-have-no-idea-whats-causing-it)
2. [Rails uninitialised constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303856/rails-uninitialised-constant-activesupportautoload-nameerror?lq=1)

Comment: It doesn't seem relevant to your capybara error, but you shouldn't need to `require 'activesupport'` or `require 'rails/all'` in your spec_helper.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I couldn't get it to work even with your answer @auL5agoi, and had to resort to restarting the project with the exact gem versions prescribed by the tutorial, after which it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put everything in one group, I think it's worth a try. like:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.0.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>=2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '>=2.4.1'
end
```

And this helped me out:

I put this into my spec_helper.rb

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

This might be an overkill but what I also did is:

spec_helper.rb:

```
require "capybara"
```

I have also encountered strange behavior when running the test right out the current directory.
To fix that just move 1 directory up and run it like so:

```
bundle exec rspec specs/features/examples_spec.rb
```